# Automatically cast interface to correct concrete type before overloading

Tags: c#, interface, overloading

I have an interface that is implemented by multiple concrete classes and a method that is overloaded for each concrete class (the example is just for illustration purposes) :

```
class IShape 
{
    /* ... */
}
class Square : IShape
{ 
    /* ... */ 
}
class Circle : IShape
{
    /* ... */
}
void toPng(Square a)
{
    /* ... */
}
void toPng(Circle b)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Here's what i would like to do :

```
/* Here i know that shape is castable to one of the concrete types */ 
Shape shape = Deserialize(jsonString);
toPng(shape) // Error : Cannot convert from 'IShape' to 'Square'
```

I could try to cast to each concrete class but that doesn't feel ideal.

```
try
{ 
    toPng( (Square)shape ) 
}
catch { /* ... */ }
try
{ 
    toPng( (Circle)shape ) 
}
catch { /* ... */ }
```

Is there a way to automatically cast the interface to the correct concrete type before overloading happens ? Somehow i couldn't find anything on the internet.

[edit] I should note that i'd rather not modify the interface and its concrete implementations in my situation, so putting `toPng()` in the interface contract is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Either add toPng() to yout IShape interface or as virtual method to a base class of all your concrete classes, the override in the concrete classes.

Comment: sorry i should have precised that i'd rather not modify the base classes, as they are not code that i own directly

Answer (score 1):

You want to defer member lookup until you know the runtime type of a variable.

That's what [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) is for. It does the member lookup at runtime instead of compiletime.

```
/* Here i know that shape is castable to one of the concrete types */ 
dynamic shape = Deserialize(jsonString);
toPng(shape)
```

Although you need to be aware - you're essentially asserting that you *know* that it'll find an appropriate member at runtime - if the member lookup in fact fails, because `shape` turned out to be an `Elephant` - you'll get a runtime error.