# Casting interface to concreate class at runtime via list of Types implementing interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting

**4 Edit.** I realize now that my question is flawed as I have a hard time explaining it so it makes sense. But after more reading I found this [Statically Typed or Dynamically Typed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/may/cutting-edge-using-the-dynamic-keyword-in-csharp-4-0), which contains "
...statically typed language:

- Every expression is of a type known at compile time.
- Variables are restricted to a type known at compile time"

Creating/casting a variable with/into type that is only known at runtime was basically what I wanted to know if it was possible to do. And clearly it is not. Even if I can check the type at runtime, I cannot create a variable of that type.

Unless I involve the dynamic type and have pre-defined methods on the concrete object to return itself..

---

This is more of a "is it possible" question rather than a "help I need to solve it like this"...
I have:

```
interface IFruit {}
class Apple : IFruit {}
class Pear: IFruit {}
class Banana: IFruit {}

class CuttingBoard
{
    public void Cut(Queue<IFruits> fruits) 
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> typesImplementingIFruit = ReflectionHelper.GetAllTypesThatImplementInterface<IFruit >(typeof(IFruit ).Assembly);

         while(fruits.Count != 0) 
         {
            var fruit = fruits.Dequeue();

           // can I somehow, cast fruit to the concrete class using the typesImplementingIFruit that contains all three concrete types ?

          // **2 Edit**, like this:
          foreach(var t in typesImplementingIFruit) 
          {
              if(fruit.GetType() == t) 
              {
                 var concrete = fruit as t;
                 break;
              }
          }
          // end of 2 Edit
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of different concepts with TypeConverters and Reflection combining the Types in typesImplementingIFruit and the IFruit dequeued without any success.

[This is a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717879/automatically-cast-interface-to-correct-concrete-type-before-overloading) but I do not see how I can use dynamic in my case and/or what good it would do as a step towards a concrete reference.

Just to guard against it, I know I can use "if (fruit is Apple)" or "switch(fruit) case Apple" but that is a solution not using the list of Types implementing the interface

**1 Edit:**

I do not want to expand the interface, use abstractions or other methods that would make sense as it would break the example. Unless off-course a change would make it possible to get the concrete class..

This feels kind of similar: [reflection to call generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) but it involves calling methods not casting.

My guess at the moment is that my example is not possible to solve, and I'm happy if that is the answer so I can move on :)

**3 Edit.**

I'll try to re-code the question.

```
static void EatApple(Apple apple)
{ }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object apple = new Apple() { Size = 30 };
 
    EatApple(??apple??);
}
```

Is it possible to somehow, at runtime, make the object into an apple reference so I can be used as argument into `EatApple`?

Like this, but without the self method in Apple

```
class Apple 
{
    public int Size;

    public Apple Self()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

class Program 
{
    static void EatApple(Apple apple)
    { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object apple = new Apple() { Size = 30 };
        var sameApple = ((dynamic)apple).Self();

        EatApple(sameApple);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think a type can be casted to an instance of this type? Moreover, it's possible that there are no instances of this type in your application at all. But you are always able to create a new instance via [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance) method. Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Sry, but why don't you benefit from polymorphism by declaring stuff onto `IFruit` directly

Comment: Following what @andriy pointed out, you can declare methods or properties on `IFruit` that each fruit must implement (for example, `bool MustBePeeled { get; }`). Then each fruit would implement them (for example, Banana could have `public bool ShouldBePeeled => true;`, while the others could return false. That's a cleaner way than doing a pattern matching `switch` on the type: `switch (fruit.GetType()) { case Apple apple:  DoSomethingWithApple(apple); break; etc`

Comment: If you can live with single inheritance, make `Fruit` an abstract class and give it default implementations for the various things you can do to a fruit. The various fruits can then override them as needed

Comment: @Dmitry - I have no clue, but my feeling is that it is not possible :) If I use CreateInstance I cannot go for the generic version (correct me if I am wrong) and as such will be left with an instance of type Object instead of the interface. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Flydog57 I should have been more clear in the question, but doing any your suggested changes still leaves me in the dark if it is possible or not only with the "tools" in my example.

Comment: @Andriy Shevchenko I should have been more clear in the question, but doing any your suggested changes still leaves me in the dark if it is possible or not only with the "tools" in my example.

Comment: I can't figure out this: "can I cast fruit to the concrete class using the typesImplementingIFruit". `typesImplementingIFruit` is IEnumerable<Type>, just a collection. Could you explain how you imagine to use it? Compare types it contains with Dequeued type?

Comment: You can use CreateInstance with generic types. Look up `Type MakeGenericType`. When you create an object using CreateInstance, it returns a `System.Object`, but it's actually an instance of the type you created. If you know the type, you can cast it. Usually though, you know the name of the type, but not _the Type_, so you can't. At that point, you end up using Reflection's `Invoke` method. Calling through an interface or a base types virtual methods is a better path

Comment: @Auditive
I added a second edit in the code example, which I hope make my wording clear

Comment: @Henrik Landström still can't figure out what you trying to achieve. If you need concrete-typed object - there is provided `is Concrete` and I see no reason to reinvent a wheel, finding more difficult ways to get concrete-typed variable. Actually, even Reflection will give you at least `object` type, not concrete. Maybe casting isn't truly what you need and there is a better way to achieve what you want, but you didn't point us with that goal. Imho (with excuse me), you wasting time on it instead of use known solution.

Comment: @Auditive I am trying to understand if it is possible or not from a "learning more" perspective, there is no problem at hand that require a solution.

For sure, I am so lacking in knowledge that I have a hard time framing the question.

But, if the best I can get is an object and I can close the question and say: thank you for taking your time giving me a bit more knowledge :)

Comment: *"Like this, but without the self method in Apple"* - `var sameApple = (Apple)apple;`, It without self but with explicit cast. You still need `if` or `is` or `switch` to define proper concrete type to downcast.

Comment: @Auditive Using (Apple)apple would mean I need to know which type to cast into at compile, I cannot check the type and then cast into it. As per my 4 edit.
And I think that link was what I needed to close this. Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In my 4th edit, at the top of the question, I have found a link that basically states that the answer to my question is:

- No.
- Not possible in a statically-typed language.

Thanks to all helpful comments that pushed my into searching for more ways to ask the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Partially yes you can, no you shouldn't. Your question is answered by [Getting all types that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface), you need to scan assemblies for implementors of your interface, and then check your `fruit` instance against that list.

But you should not need such code, unless you're writing a serializer or code generator. If you have a method that accepts input in the form of an interface, you should not care who implements that interface.

If your `CuttingBoard` promises that it can `Cut(IFruit fruit)` (or a collection of `IFruit`), then it knows how to cut any `IFruit`. You should not care in that method what kinds of fruit you'll be passed. It promises it knows how to, and knows how to based on the members of the IFruit interface. They either have properties determining the kind of knife or surface or whatever of the fruit, or the fruit itself has a `Cut(...)` method that it will call.

Or to ask it differently, if you know here that `t` is `Apple`, but your code might not know `Apple` (because it's in a whole different assembly), how would the rest of your code change to use `t` or `concrete`?

```
if(fruit.GetType() == t) {
    var concrete = fruit as t;
    break;
}
```

You can't determine `var` and `t` at runtime if `t` is not a known-at-compile-time or generic type.

Comment: Hi, 
I 100% agree I do not need this code for something practical, it is just that I get it into my head sometimes that I would like to do it and I think it is impossible but somehow I still keep thinking about the topic. I added a 3d edit, with a different piece of code, maybe it makes better sense to the question?

By differnet assemblies, you mean if the IFruit is in one assembly and Apple is in another? And if the code only as the interface assembly it can never find a match?